# How to apply a filter ( dplyr) in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, filter, visualization

I'm trying to fill some specific areas of my geographic map with the purple color and I have no problem in doing that. This is the script I'm using:

```
right_join(prov2022, database, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = `wage` > 500 & `wage` <=1000))+
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('white', 'purple'))
```

But now I want to apply a filter in my ggplot2 picture.
I need to fill the areas of the map, but only those that have the value 13 in the column(variable) COD_REG.
I have added   *filter( COD_REG == 13)* but it doesn't work

```
right_join(prov2022, database, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  filter( COD_REG == 13)
  ggplot(aes(fill = `wage` > 500 & `wage` <=1000))+
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('white', 'purple'))
```

R answers

```
> right_join(prov2022, database, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
+   filter( COD_REG == 13)
Error in `stopifnot()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = COD_REG == 13`.
✖ Input `..1` must be of size 106 or 1, not size 107.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

My database has 106 obs and 13 variables and it is like this

```
COD_REG   COD_PROV   wage
1         91         530
1         92         520
1         93         510
2         97         500
2         98         505
2         99         501
13        102        700
13        103        800   
13        109        900
```

Where is the mistake?
Why R answers << ✖ Input `..1` must be of size 106 or 1, not size 107. >> ??
How can I solve???

Comment: Provide example data to reproduce the error.

Comment: @zx8754 I've added it right now, you can find it in the body of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have another `filter` function that shadows the dplyr one. Also you have forgot to add a `%>%` after your filter. Could you try this:

```
right_join(prov2022, database, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  dplyr::filter(COD_REG == 13) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = `wage` > 500 & `wage` <=1000))+
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('white', 'purple'))
```

---

The code runs as expected with the sample data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- "COD_REG   COD_PROV   wage
1         91         530
1         92         520
1         93         510
2         97         500
2         98         505
2         99         501
13        102        700
13        103        800
13        109        900"

read_table(data) |> 
  filter(COD_REG == 13)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   COD_REG COD_PROV  wage
#>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      13      102   700
#> 2      13      103   800
#> 3      13      109   900
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you peter! But it still doesn't work :( ... It gives me the same error. To be sure I've also run library(dplyr) to be sure that the filter command isn't covered by anything else, but it doesn't change

Comment: then we probably need some example data that reproduces the error to figure out what's going wrong. Is `COD_REG` a column in the dataset?

Comment: I've added it right now, you can find it in the body of the question

Comment: It works fine with your example data. See edit.